# Python: check string using re.match

Tags: python, regex

I need to write func to check str. If should fit next conditions:

1) str should starts with alphabet - `^[a-zA-Z]`

2) str may contains alphabet, numbers, one `.` and one `-`

3) str should ends with alphabet or number

4) length of str should be from 1 to 50

```
def check_login(str):
    flag = False
    if match(r'^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,50}[a-zA-Z0-9]$', str):
        flag = True
    return flag
```

But it should mean that it starts with alphabet, length of `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` is more than 0 and less 51 and it ends with `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.
How can I limit quantity of `.` and `-` and write length's limit to all expression?

I mean that `a` - should returns true, `qwe123` also true.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need lookaheads:

```
^                              # start of string
    (?=^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)        # not a dot, 0+ times, a dot eventually, not a dot
    (?=^[^-]*-?[^-]*$)         # same with dash
    (?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]$)         # [A-Za-z0-9] in the end
    [A-Za-z][-.A-Za-z0-9]{,49} 
$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ph89yR/4/).

---

Which in `Python` might be:

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'''
^                        # start of string
    (?=^[^.]*\.?[^.]*$)  # not a dot, 0+ times, a dot eventually, not a dot
    (?=^[^-]*-?[^-]*$)   # same with dash
    (?=.*[A-Za-z0-9]$)   # [A-Za-z0-9] in the end
    [A-Za-z][-.A-Za-z0-9]{,49} 
$
''', re.VERBOSE)

strings = ['qwe123', 'qwe-123', 'qwe.123', 'qwe-.-123', '123-']

def check_login(string):
    if rx.search(string):
        return True
    return False

for string in strings:
    print("String: {}, Result: {}".format(string, check_login(string)))
```

This yields:

```
String: qwe123, Result: True
String: qwe-123, Result: True
String: qwe.123, Result: True
String: qwe-.-123, Result: False
String: 123-, Result: False
```

Comment: `.123` (and the family) ?

Comment: @CristiFati: Updated the demo link (wrong version linked, initially).

Comment: But if I check one alphabet symbol for example `q` it returns False, but it should returns True

Comment: I'm being picky, but `\w` allows `_` :). Anyway, nice answer.

Comment: @CristiFati: Right you are, one needs to write it out in full if this matters.

Comment: @CristiFati: Updated once again - need to go to bed, obviously.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you advice some tutorial to explore regex?

Comment: @PetrPetrov: You are very welcome. Start with https://regexone.com/ and move your way up to http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://rexegg.com/ (the best imo, but very advanced, indeed).